# Entity framework: order by and dynamic sort key

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Entity framework: order by and dynamic sort key

I have this query and it works fine

```
tmpList = db.Book.OrderBy(Function(t) t.id)
```

But i need to order depending on a field, something like this (sortField is a string with the name of the column:id, name, description...)

```
tmpList = db.Book.OrderBy(sortField)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic linq for that.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension methods to sort by property name:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
{
    // LAMBDA: x => x.[PropertyName]
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
    Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

    // REFLECTION: source.OrderBy(x => x.Property)
    var orderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "OrderBy" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    var orderByGeneric = orderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), property.Type);
    var result = orderByGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });

    return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)result;
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [EntityFramework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/).

You can find other methods to order by property name in my repository:

- OrderByDescending
- ThenBy
- ThenByDescending
- AddOrAppendOrderBy
- AddOrAppendOrderByDescending